# Why might my Vue.js project not show up during a CircleCI test using Cypress?

Tags: vue.js, circleci, nuxt.js, cypress

- My project is built using Vue.js, powered by [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/)
- I’m using [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) to write/run tests
- I’m using [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/) (v2) to run the tests

Locally, using Cypress’s instance of the Electron browser on macOS, the tests run correctly.

On CircleCI, the tests display a blank screen.

[image: Blank test screen]

I’ve SSHed into CircleCI after the tests have failed, and if I make a `curl` request to the local server at that address, the correct HTML is returned to me.

My hypothesis is that the browser is not able to run Vue.js, but without a console log it’s hard to tell.

Any ideas as either how to continue debugging, or even better, fix it?

---

Edit: I’ve written an extra test to use another site, and it loaded correctly, so I can confirm that everything else is working.

---

Edit: It’s in my Nuxt config, just going through it now to pull out the line causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

So, of course this was super annoying. I’m not sure what the chances are of this happening to somebody else, but here’s the answer to my problem:

### Google Analytics

On my CI I don’t have a GA code, and it was falling back to empty string, so it wasn’t able to load the page. It didn’t show up on the sever logs as it was an issue on the client side, and it’s not yet possible to easily get client logs using Cypress (coming soon).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, Thomas,

Could you open a GitHub issue with a link to a small repo that we can try ourselves? I do not see any factors that might affect running Cypress tests against Nuxt app on Circle

Comment: I think it’s Vue.js causing the problem! Will make something testable and open – thank you!

Comment: So I’ve made a brand new repo and it, of course, it works perfectly. It must be something in my Nuxt config, going to keep debugging.

Comment: Turns out it was because I didn’t have a Google Analytics key setup on Circle. D’oh.